# BottomNavigation component in svelte native

Tags: typescript, nativescript, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-native

I'm currently working on integrating a BottomNavigation component into my Svelte Native application and encountering some difficulties. It appears that BottomNavigation was deprecated from the core project and has been replaced by a community plugin (@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation). After installing this community plugins, I'm facing TypeScript errors indicating a mismatch in component extension - TypeScript expects a different base component than the one used in the library.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any documentation or working examples online that address this issue. Would anyone be able to assist me with this? Perhaps there's a viable workaround, an alternative library, or a component that I could use? Maybe I'm also just missing a step in the implementation, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!